# ¿Como hago con .fadeToggle() hacer aparecer varios elementos?

Tags: jquery

La cosa es que quería que al clicar un "botón" (lo pongo entre comillas porque solo es botón en apariencia) se me desplegase diferentes opciones.

Esto lo hago con la animación de `Jquery` `.fadeToggle()`

¿Porque solo se me despliega la primera opción?¿Como hago para que se muestren todas? (En este caso todas son 2).

Código:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('#Btn-Selector-Rutina').click(function() {
    $('#Btn-Subselector-Rutina').fadeToggle();
  });
});
```

```css
.Btn-Selector {
  height: auto;
  width: 200px;
  padding: 5px;
  text-align: center;
  margin: auto;
  border: solid 2px;
  border-color: #21211d;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#Btn-Subselector-Rutina {
  display: none;
  border-top-style: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="Selector-Rutina">
  <p class="Btn-Selector" id="Btn-Selector-Rutina">Tipo de rutina</p>

  <p class="Btn-Selector" id="Btn-Subselector-Rutina">Rutina 1</p>
  <p class="Btn-Selector" id="Btn-Subselector-Rutina">Rutina 2</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Buenas!, está mal usar dos elementos con el mismo ID ya que sólo se va a reconocer al primer elemento que contenga el ID especificado. Recomiendo usar Class o un atributo personalizado en estos casos.

Por otro lado, para referirte a muchos elementos con un Class o un atributo o elementos de igual tipo, podés usar `$.each()`, aunque si fueran elementos con distintos nombres, podés usar `$(#id, elemento, .class, otro).on(...)`.

Te dejo un ejemplo:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>
    <style type="text/css">

        .Btn-Selector {
          height: auto;
          width: 200px;
          padding: 5px;
          text-align: center;
          margin: auto;
          border: solid 2px;
          border-color: #21211d;
          cursor: pointer;
        }

        .Btn-Selector:not(#Btn-Selector-Rutina) {
          display: none;
          border-top-style: none;
        }

    </style>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {

          $('#Btn-Selector-Rutina').click(function() {
            $.each($('.Btn-Selector:not(#Btn-Selector-Rutina)'), function() {
                $(this).fadeToggle();
            });
          });

        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>

    <div id="Selector-Rutina">
        <p class="Btn-Selector" id="Btn-Selector-Rutina">Tipo de rutina</p>
        <p class="Btn-Selector">Rutina 1</p>
        <p class="Btn-Selector">Rutina 2</p>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```